# How to benchmark OMPL-planner solutions?

Tags: ros, motion-planning, arm-navigation, ompl-ros-interface, motion-planners

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

How to benchmark OMPL-planner solutions if we use the ompl_ros_interface?

I wish there is a standard way to do so as if we use the standalone OMPL (see [this tutorial](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/benchmark.html)).

What do you think?
How do you usually accommodate such use case?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38338/how-to-benchmark-ompl-planner-solutions?/) by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the very late response -- the plannerarena.org website is not fully functional yet (I still need help to work on it!)
However, a benchmarking infrastructure similar to that of OMPL is available for ROS now, as part of MoveIt!, which will be released shortly, once ROS Groovy comes out.

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2012-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://plannerarena.org/ provides benchmark results for various problem sets for algorithms from OMPL in ROS setup.

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on 2012-07-10**:
Thanks indeed for the link, prince. Btw, we can not download the benchmarking software, can't we? Also, is it done using the OMPL inside ROS? ... because I would like to benchmark them on my specific planning problems. Thanks again!

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-07-10**:
Homepage of website states the use of OMPL and ROS.  I will advise you to contact on website for benchmarking software. I do not know about its public release status.